# python graph-tool cuts off edges

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

graph-tool for python is cutting off my edges, and I can't seem to fix it, no matter how much I hack... help!  Changing the output size does nothing.

Also, my edge text looks like crud.  Any suggestions?

```
graph_draw(g, vertex_shape = vs, vertex_text = vl, vertex_font_size = 18, edge_text = el, edge_font_size = 40, edge_text_distance = 0,
           edge_marker_size = 30, output_size = (400,400), vertex_size = 40, output = "output.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the `fit_view = False` option to `graph_draw()`, it will not attempt to scale the drawing to fit the output size. You can then choose your view by changing the posions of the nodes, such that it does not exclude any part of the graph:

```
g = random_graph(10, lambda: 10, self_loops=True, directed=False)
pos = sfdp_layout(g)
x, y = ungroup_vector_property(pos, [0, 1])
x.a = (x.a - x.a.min()) / (x.a.max() - x.a.min()) * 200 + 100
y.a = (y.a - y.a.min()) / (y.a.max() - y.a.min()) * 200 + 100
pos = group_vector_property([x, y])
graph_draw(g, pos, output_size=(400, 400), output="foo.png", fit_view=False)
```

[image]

You can improve the edge labels by tuning the properties `text_distance`, `text_parallel` and `font_size`.